# Axios interceptor doesn't work on App.js but yes in another file

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, react-router

hope you doing well.

I've got my private routes on the app.js, but when adding the interceptor to catch errors (401), it doesn't work. Im always getting "err.response not defined".

But when i move the private routes along the interceptor to another file, is working , but the routes won't render and i get a blank page.

Im not sure where is the problem, but im think is related to the app.js file and his defaults settings. Im using laravel as a backend.

Here is my app.js where the interceptor wont work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import axios from "./axios-instance";
import Homepage from './pages/home/homepage';
import Login from './pages/admin/login';
import Admin from './pages/admin/admin';
import Adminhouses from './pages/admin/adminhouses';



function App() {
  const [adminAuthenticated, setAdminAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`api/checkAuthenticated`).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log(res);
        setAdminAuthenticated(true);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => {
      setAdminAuthenticated(false);
    };
  }, []);

  axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function axiosRetryInterceptor(err) {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      history.push('/');
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });

  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error.response.status === 403)// acces denied
    {
      history.push('/login')
    }
    else if (error.response.status === 404)// page not found
    {
      history.push('404')
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
  );

  let routes = (
    <>

      <Route exact path="/">
        <Homepage />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/admin">
        <Admin />
      </Route>
      

    </>
  );

  if (adminAuthenticated) {

    if (loading) {
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }
    routes = (
      <>

        <Route exact path="/admin">
          <Admin />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/admin/houses">
          <Adminhouses />
        </Route>

      </>
    );
  }


  return (
    <Router>

      <Switch>

        <Route exact path="/">
          <Homepage />
        </Route>


        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        {routes}



      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my axios-instance

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  config.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
  return config;
});

export default axios;
```

This is my other file ADMINPRIVATE

```
import axios from "../axios-instance";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Admin from "../pages/admin/admin";
import Adminhouses from "../pages/admin/adminhouses";
import Homepage from "../pages/home/homepage";
import Login from "../pages/admin/login";


function Adminprivate() {


    const [adminAuthenticated, setAdminAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`api/checkAuthenticated`).then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log(res);
                setAdminAuthenticated(true);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return () => {
            setAdminAuthenticated(false);
        };
    }, []);

    axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function axiosRetryInterceptor(err) {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
            history.push('/');
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error.response.status === 403)// acces denied
        {
            history.push('/login')
        }
        else if (error.response.status === 404)// page not found
        {
            history.push('404')
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
    );
    let routes = (
        <>
            <Route exact path="/admin">
                <Admin />
            </Route>
        </>
    );

    if (adminAuthenticated) {
       
        routes = (
            <>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/admin">
                            <Admin />
                        </Route>

                        <Route path="/admin/houses">
                            <Adminhouses />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </>
        );
    }



}
export let routes = (


    <>

        <Route exact path="/">
            <Homepage />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/login">
            <Login />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/admin">
            <Admin />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/admin/houses">
            <Adminhouses />
        </Route>

    </>







);
export default Adminprivate;
```

So there is the thing. Private routes on app.js = interceptor doesn't work.
Private routes on different file + interceptor = Routes won't show up, but interceptors works.

Im not sure why is that, any information will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Why are you declaring the interceptors as unintentional side-effects? Try moving them into the `useEffect` callback. ***OR*** why aren't the interceptors declared normally as part of the `axios` configuration? Also, I'm pretty sure you ***don't*** want to enqueue a `setAdminAuthenticated(false);` state update in any `useEffect` cleanup function when the component has unmounted.

Comment: I highly recommend creating separate Axios instances if you need different behaviour for specific endpoints. Then they can have their own configuration (interceptors, baseURL, default headers etc). You should also decouple your Axios code from your components... create separate service modules that return promises that can be consumed by your components

Comment: I've solved part of the problem, now  it redirects always to the ("/"), no matter what i do. Is like the useEffect cheking on the (api/checkAuthenticated) is always checking.

Comment: I had to wrap index.js in to router to resolve that 'history is not defined', now im struggling with that admin check that always loads